# How to separate unit and integration tests with Gradle and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, gradle

I want get a configuration what allow me run unit and integartion tests independently both from Gradle and from Eclipse. So, I have a `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'java-library'
}

description = 'Cool library'
group = 'org.coollib'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
    targetCompatibility = '17'
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.fazecast:jSerialComm:2.10.2'

      // tests
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2'
      testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.4.0'
}

sourceSets {
    integration {
        java.srcDir "$projectDir/src/integration/java"
        resources.srcDir "$projectDir/src/integration/resources"
        compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integration.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest


tasks.named('test') {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.named('integrationTest') {
    // Use JUnit Platform for integration unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

With this `build.gradle` I can run from Gradle task `test` for unit-tests and task `check` which runs each build, for run both unit and integration tests. But from Eclipse if I click on menu item "Run As / JUnit Test" on the source folder `src/test/java` all tests are runs not only unit tests, despite the fact that in "Run Configurations" the option "Run all tests in teh selected project, package or source folder" are set to the source folder `src/test/java`, as shown in figure below:

[image]

So how can I separate unit and integration tests in Eclipse?